# PHP extract array values to be added in another arrays

Tags: php, arrays

How to extract array values, then creating another arrays with the one of the items is taken from the value.

I have the the following code below.

Base code below:

```
$order_id = 325;
$fruits = ["Apple","Blueberry","Coconut"];
$date_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Then create new arrays like these below:

```
// These $var should be incrementing depends the $fruits values. (e.g: $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4 and so on..)
$var1 = [
        "order_id" => 325,
        "fruit_name" => "Apple",
        "date_created" => $date_created
        ];

$var2 = [
        "order_id" => 325,
        "fruit_name" => "Blueberry",
        "date_created" => $date_created
        ];

$var3 = [
        "order_id" => 325,
        "fruit_name" => "Coconut",
        "date_created" => $date_created
        ];
```

Result must be like below:

```
// The Result I wondering should be like this:
$array = [
        $var1,
        $var2,
        $var3,
        // $var4 if any..
        ];
```

Thank you for your help in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($fruits as $f) {
    $array[] = array(
        "order_id" => $order_id,
        "fruit_name" => $f,
        "date_created" => $date_created
    );
}
```

There should be no need for `$var1`, `$var2`, etc. Just push the new elements directly onto the array.

Answer (score 0):

as your said `These $var should be incrementing depends the $fruits values` ,so I made a little code by variable increment.

```
<?php
 $order_id = 325;
 $fruits = ["Apple","Blueberry","Coconut"];
 $date_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $array = array();
  foreach ($fruits as $key => $value) {
    ${"var{$key}"} = array();//will get $var0,$var1,....etc
    ${"var{$key}"}["order_id"] = $order_id;
    ${"var{$key}"}["fruit_name"] = $value;
    ${"var{$key}"}["date_create()"] = $date_created;
 }    
 $array = [$var0,$var1,$var2];
 var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of variable variables. There's practically never a use for them.

Comment: yes , I know it ,I just give the hint that he asked ! But Thanks for your comment.